# Can go protobuf marshal message to an already allocated byte array without copy?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, ipc, packet

I am implementing client server communication by self defined packets.
I am using Go `net.conn`. It can dial tcp/unix schemes which is very convenient. I use `protocol buffer` to define my messages.

I defined a Packet which contains `length` and `buffer`

```
type Packet struct {
    length uint32
    buffer []byte
}
```

The API function is like this:
`func(api *API) Send(m *proto.Message) error`
`func(api *API) Receive(p *Packet) error`

Take `send` function as an example, it takes in a protobuf message, marshal it into `Packet`. And write it to the `net.conn`.

Here is a simplified version of the Send function:

```
func(api *API) Send(m *proto.Message) error {
    bytes, err := proto.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    buffer := api.packet[:length]
    copy(buffer, bytes)
    _, err := api.conn.Write(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I was copying `bytes` into `buffer`. Because Go protocol buffer API only provides
 `func Marshal(pb Message) ([]byte, error)`

In protocol buffer C++, it provides
`bool SerializeToArray(void * data, int size) const`, which is serializing the message and storing it in the given byte array.
But I can not find the same thing in Go protocol buffer API.

Is there any way to avoid the copy if I want to directly storing serialized result in the given byte array?

Comment: Could you please clarify a few things: Why is the packet stored in a field of the API and where does this length come from? Is all you really want to do writing a byte array consisting of the length (4 bytes) and then the actual message to the connection?

Comment: What about accepting an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [MarshalTo](https://godoc.org/github.com/gogo/protobuf/plugin/marshalto) method from `gogo/protobuf`, another implementation of protobuf, compatible with the original.

You can re-use the same buffer through multiple marshal calls as you pass it the buffer to be filled. Obviously the buffer should be big enough.

```
func MarshalTo([]byte, m) error
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking. Notice that the proto Marshal() function does exactly what you are looking for: It serializes the message into a byte slice (what you probably mean by byte array)

See if either of these help:

```
func(api *API) Send(m *proto.Message) error {
    p := Packet{}
    p.buffer, err := proto.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err := api.conn.Write(p.buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Or

```
func(api *API) Send(m *proto.Message) error {
    buffer := api.packet[:length]
    buffer, err := proto.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err := api.conn.Write(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: My purpose is to put the serialized buffer into the `packet`, instead of writing it directly to `conn`.  because the packet was already used by other components for my project. I can not refactor it. `proto.Marshal` returns `[]byte` and was copied into my packet. I am seeking a way to avoid the copy. An example is protobuf C++ API, it can marshal message into an `already allocated buffer`.  But go protobuf can only return it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can make `Packet.buffer` to be a [`proto.Buffer`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Buffer)

```
type Packet struct {
    length uint32
    buffer proto.Buffer
}
...
var packet Packet
packet.length = YouLength
packet.buffer = proto.NewBuffer(make([]byte, YouLength))
//Then you can Marshall in Packet directly and it  may be reused.
err := packet.Marshal(message)
```